# Cannot add data connection in Visual studio 2008

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to add SQL Server database file using VS2008, but I got an error said this server version is not supported. Only servers up to Microsoft SQL Server 2005 are supported. I tried to delete the Microsoft SQL Server Data\SQLEXPRESS folder and reconnected it, but I still got the same error.

here is an error what i got. Does anyone know how to fix it?
[image]

Thank you so much, 
Eva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the information in this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc440724(v=vs.90).aspx.

It seems that you need VS2008 sp1 installed to work with SQL 2008.